# Firebase's AngularFire in an AngularJS service

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularjs-service, angularfire

The best way of handling Firebase in AngularJS surely has to be from within a service, so it's available to all Controllers across the App.

I just can't get it to work! ... I first tried using `angularFire(new Firebase(url))`, hoping I could bind to the service's scope, but Angular complains that it cannot `$watch` it.

So I tried angularFireCollection instead like this:

```
app.factory('myService', function myService(angularFireCollection) {
    var url = 'https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com';
    return {
        getAll: function(path) {
            var ref = angularFireCollection(new Firebase(url + '/' + path));
            console.log(ref);
            return ref;
        },
        ...
    };
});
```

However, the angularFireCollection is an Object containing a load of methods etc. if I bind it to a controller $scope I just get garbage. It also complains that it can't call the Firebase functions before I try to use them (e.g. `Error: Firebase.push failed: second argument must be a valid function.`)... anyone got any ideas where I'm going wrong?

**See this [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/3Hplw7)**

Comment: I think angularFire already is a service so you could use it just as it is.

Comment: well ... angularFire is a service, but it provides binding to the $scope you choose to apply it to e.g. `angularFire(new Firebase(url), $scope, 'value');`. That's great if I just want to use it in one Controller, but I want to be able to bind to a custom service so that I can access/edit/update the data from any controller, just by passing around the service. The Firebase site only shows you how to bind [implicitly](http://angularfire.com/documentation.html#implicit) and [explicitly](http://angularfire.com/documentation.html#explicit) to the current $scope.

Comment: It is really amazing that there is no simple answer (nor Firebase example) for this question, regarding that AngularJS promotes using angular services to share state/services between controllers. Therefore, upvoted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to encapsulate some of the functionality into a service, consider keeping the returned ref in state of the service. I expanded on your plunker. It seems to mostly do what you were trying for.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Uf2fB0

Comment: **you star!!** ... that's exactly what I was after.

Comment: it seems I spoke too soon ... I don't think this works as expected. It binds to a specific scope, but not the service. And it only lets you bind (setToScope) once. The point of the service was so that we could access the model from any controller without using rootScope. I'd like to be able to bind the model to the service context and then be able to update the Firebase by editing objects on the service model. Or maybe I've misunderstood how to use the service.

Comment: ok ... I think I get this now, and I was wrong ... it does let you bind to multiple scopes. I made a couple of changes to demo how I'm wanting to use this see the new [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/A7UfPj)

Comment: Thank you for this. Helped me with my project

Answer (score 6):

Jeff answered the question correctly ... I'm just posting a further development on Jeff's example for those who are interested.

I have abstracted the Firebase service creation, so you can dynamically create an instance of whatever Firebase service you want:-

```
var registerFirebaseService = function (serviceName) {
    app.factory(serviceName, function (angularFire) {
        var _url = null;
        var _ref = null;

        return {
            init: function (url) {
                _url = url;
                _ref = new Firebase(_url);
            },
            setToScope: function (scope, localScopeVarName) {
                angularFire(_ref, scope, localScopeVarName);
            }
        };
    });
};
```

You first create an instance of the service as follows

```
registerFirebaseService('itemsService'); // create itemsService instance
```

Then you can inject the `itemsService` service into your controllers. The instance is initialised using your Firebase URL e.g.

```
itemsService.init('https://firebase.firebaseio.com/' + userId + '/items');
```

The Firebase can now be bound to your controller e.g.

```
itemsService.setToScope($scope, 'items');
```

**adapted [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/P2prkZ)**